# How to get data in array using foreach in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

How to get data using for each, if the data name is already display it should repeat again. like for example in this photo.[image]

here's the code:

`list.component.ts`

```
 this.gaugeOption = [];

    this.global.getData(`/services/getData.php`)
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe((res: any) => {
        this.rowData = res;
        console.log(this.rowData)
        this.rowData.forEach(room => {
          this.gaugeOption.push({
            title: {
              text: room.sensor,
              left: '5%',
              top: '5%',
              textStyle: {
                fontSize: 18,
              }
            },
            tooltip: {
              formatter: "{a} <br/>{b} : {c}°"
            },
            toolbox: {
              show: true,
              feature: {
                mark: { show: false },
                restore: { show: false },
                saveAsImage: { show: false }
              }
            },
            series: [
              {
                name: 'Temperature',
                type: 'gauge',
                center: ['40%', '70%'],
                splitNumber: 10,
                radius: '70%',
                axisLine: {
                  lineStyle: {
                    color: [[0.2, '#48b'], [0.8, '#228b22'], [1, '#ff0000']],
                    width: 8
                  }
                },
                axisTick: {
                  splitNumber: 10,
                  length: 12,
                  lineStyle: {
                    color: 'auto'
                  }
                },
                axisLabel: {
                  textStyle: {
                    color: 'auto'
                  }
                },
                splitLine: {
                  show: true,
                  length: 30,
                  lineStyle: {
                    color: 'auto'
                  }
                },
                pointer: {
                  width: 5
                },
                title: {
                  show: true,
                  offsetCenter: [0, '65%'],
                  textStyle: {
                    fontWeight: 'bolder'
                  }
                },
                detail: {
                  formatter: '{value}°',
                  textStyle: {
                    color: 'auto',
                    fontWeight: 'bolder'
                  }
                },
                data: [{ value: room.temperature, name: "Temperature" }]
              }
            ]
          });
        });

    });
```

`list.component.html`

```
 <ul class="cards">
        <li class="cards__item" *ngFor="let data of gaugeOption; let i = index">
          <div class="card">
            <div echarts [options]="data" id="{{'chart-' + i}}" [autoResize]="true"></div>
            <div class="card__content">
              <!-- <div class="card__title">Flex Basis</div> -->
                <!-- <p class="card__text">This defines the default size of an element before the remaining space is distributed.
                  It can be a length (e.g. 20%, 5rem, etc.) or a keyword. The auto keyword means "look at my width or height
                  property."</p> -->
              <!-- <button class="btn btn--block card__btn">Button</button> -->
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
      </ul>
```

it should not repeated, when the first data name is already displayed.
it should when the name is already displayed it will not display and it will get the latest dateandtime, for example, there's dateandtime which there's 2 data  `10-27-2019 08:00:02` and `10-27-2019 08:22:02` it will get the latest

thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: It is really confusing what you are explaining here. I don't get what you actually want. Maybe try to reformulate your question to be understandable for 3rd. Please also consider using map instead of the foreach/push combination.

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm how to use the map?

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm in the output there's around 20 SewingSection, it should be one output instead 20 SewingSection.

Comment: improve formatting

Answer (score 0):

Then simply use find to get the first display element within res

```
 this.global.getData(`/services/getData.php`)
  .pipe(
    map(res => res.find(entry => entry.name === 'display')), // res is an array here
    take(1)
  )
  .subscribe((res: any) => { // res is a single element here
```

Comment: Parameter 'entry' implicitly has an 'any' type

Comment: Property 'take' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction<unknown, any>'.

Comment: Avoid, any types. Type correctly where you can. Second error likely comes from my missing ,. I added it

Comment: Parameter 'entry' implicitly has an 'any' type. this one